# How to secure data that needs to be used raw

Tags: php, security, paypal

I have an application that needs securing. The data is data from Paypal that allow me to charge people (if they have approved me), something I want to make sure before I launch this feature on my site is, its secure.

I know with passwords you can use salts and 1 way hashing, but as this data needs to be used in its raw format I'm wondering of ways I can store this data.

The data will not be available to the users or me, but It will be stored in a database and I'm wanting to make it so if the database gets hacked then there is nothing of 'value'.

Can anyone offer me any advice or solutions to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [PHP's Mcrypt functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) are what you're looking for. They allow the encryption and decryption of data with keys and so on. All you'd have to do is encrypt the data you wish to secure before storing it in the database. You could also decrypt them with the same passphrase as you encrypted them with when they're needed.